# Websocket Server as Service on Android Tablet

Tags: java, android, service, websocket, server

I have the following scenario.
A Websocket server, that runs on an android tablet as a service in the background.
This Service also starts Websocket client, after the Server is started to handle in-app communication. I also have a java web-socket client in a seperate project to connect and communicate with the server.

This all works fine, as long as i don't try to implement the WebSocket Server as a service.
I can connect and send data like there's no tomorrow.

But as soon as i run the Websocket server as a service i cannot connect to it any longer. Neither with my "inAppClient" nor with my seperate java client.

I set the permissions for internet in the manifest and also tried different ports. I also do portforwarding using adb forward tcp:38301 tcp:38301

The error i get when i try to connect to the server with my in-app-client is the following:
E/WSCLient﹕ Error failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 38301): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

I also tried to use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1.

This is the sourcecode for my server:

```
private class WSServer extends WebSocketServer{
        private static final String TAG = "WSServer";
//      private static final int TIMEOUT = 60;
        private int port = 38301;
        private int testLevel = Constants.BOUNCE_MESSAGES;

        public WSServer( InetSocketAddress address ) {
            super( address );
            Log.d(TAG, "creating instance of local WSServer");
            wsClient = new WSClient(port);
        }

        public WSServer(int port)
        {
            super( new InetSocketAddress( port ) );
            Log.d(TAG, "creating instance of local WSServer on port " + port);
            wsClient = new WSClient(port);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket conn, ClientHandshake handshake) {
            Log.d(TAG, "connection Details: " + conn.getLocalSocketAddress() + "; " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            Log.d(TAG, "Connection successfully opened on port: " + this.getPort());
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(WebSocket conn, int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connection closed");
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Received Message: " + message);
            if(testLevel == Constants.BOUNCE_MESSAGES)
            {
                conn.send(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date()) + ": " + message);
            }
        }

//      @Override
//      public void onFragment( WebSocket conn, Framedata fragment ) {
//          System.out.println( "received fragment: " + fragment );
//      }

        @Override
        public void onError(WebSocket conn, Exception ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError()", ex);
        }
}
```

And this is the sourcecode of my Service:

```
public CommManager(){
        wsServer = new WSServer(port);
        Log.d(TAG, "Server Adress: " + wsServer.getAddress());
    }

    public CommManager(int port){
        this.port = port;
        Log.d(TAG, "CommManager is starting");
        wsServer = new WSServer(port);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if(extras == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Port wurde nicht gesetzt. Default Port " + port + " wird verwendet");
        }
        else {
            port = (Integer)extras.get("port");
        }

        return startMode;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Binding Service to Activity");
        return commManagerBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        return allowRebind;
    }
```

And last but not least my in-app-client:

```
private class WSClient {

        public String message;
        private static final String TAG = "WSCLient";

        private WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;
        private int port = 38301;

        public WSClient(){
            connectWebSocket();
        }
        public WSClient(int port) {
            Log.d(TAG, "starting local WSClient");
            if(port != 0){
                this.port = port;
            }
            connectWebSocket();
        }

        private void connectWebSocket() {
            Log.d(TAG, "establishing Connection to local WSServer");
            URI uri;
            try {
                uri = new URI("ws://localhost:" + port);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "uri-error: " + "ws://localhost:" + port);
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
                @Override
                public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Opened");
                    mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
                }

                @Override
                public void onMessage(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "received Message: " + s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Closed " + s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error " + e.getMessage());
                }
            };
            mWebSocketClient.connect();
        }

        public void sendMessage(String message) {

            if(mWebSocketClient != null) {
                mWebSocketClient.send(message);
            }
            else {
                Log.e(TAG, "No WebSocketClient available. Trying to reconnect and create new Client instance");
                connectWebSocket();
            }
        }

    }
```

I have no clue, why i cannot establish a connection with my server.
Hopefully you can help.

Comment: I'm trying to do the exact same. May I ask what library is the WebSocketServer class from?

Comment: i'm using the following Library: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved the problem by just changing the way of my implementation. I subclassed the Server and Client classes and then it worked. :)

Comment: Could you share your complete code? I am implementing the similar service.

Comment: sorry, i no longer have access to that code, since i changed my employee

Comment: @Chao If you are still looking for some code, [this post](https://sapandiwakar.in/set-up-a-websocket-server-on-android-with-graphql-ws-protocol/) has some details.